# Запрос + квери параметры?

Tags: javascript

Как передавать такой запрос чтобы в квери-параметрах было отдельно: t, y

```
fetch("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=episode&y=2010&apikey=6ca46655", new URLSearchParams({
t: 'episode',
y: '2010',
apikey: "6ca46655"
    })
)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, так:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams({
  t: 'episode',
  y: '2010',
  apikey: '6ca46655',
}).toString();

const url = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?${params}`;

console.log(url);
```